# I am seven letters word. Find me Who Am I?

Tags: riddle, word

When I am Seven letter word,
I was founded  on same day when The Yosemite TWA crash occurred.

If you take and reverse my first three letters,
I am traditional farmhouse which is in France.

If you take my next three letters
without me the world is in darkness.

My last letter is the 7th Letter in the ISO basic Latin Alphabet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling :) I have edited your post to make it easier to read. In case you want to revert so as to hide any obvious hints, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> Samsung.

I was founded on same day when The Yosemite TWA crash occurred.

> 1 March 1938.

If you take and reverse my first three letters,
I am traditional farmhouse which is in France.

> A [mas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mas_(Proven%C3%A7al_farmhouse)) is a farmhouse.

If you take my next three letters
without me the world is in darkness.

> Sun

My last letter is the 7th Letter in the ISO basic Latin Alphabet.

> G